# ACS reviews callback

Tags: callback, comments, appcelerator, acs, review

I have an Appcelerator question.

Is there somekind of callback for new ACS reviews? One way to do this 
is to make the app refresh every x-seconds.. but this will quickly use too much resources. 
Imagine 10 people use it for 10 minutes, with auto-refresh set for 10 seconds.. it will amount to 10x6x10 = 600 API calls! And that is only for 10 people for 10 minutes, and what if they are online for 1 month??

So having a callback which notifies only if there is a **NEW** review will greatly of help here.

Is there actually a way doing this that I've missed, or other workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is through push notifications?